# Why does transform.forward appear to be void?

Tags: c#, unity

I have the following line of code from a project I'm working on:

```
this.transform.position += (keyMapping.Value * this.movementSpeed).Scale(this.transform.forward);
```

At a first glance, this line of code looks like it should work, yet, I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
error CS0019: Operator `+=' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' and `void'.
```

I'm stumped as to what might be causing this. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please note that, `this` keyword will refer to current instance of the "class" you are working on, which is a script. In your case, the code will work but you should use `gameObject` to refer the instance of GameObject you are working on. And you can use `transform` directly to refer the Transform assigned to the GameObject you are working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Vector3.Scale` with one parameter input does not return a value so you will need to apply Scale as a separate step.

```
var movement = (keyMapping.Value * this.movementSpeed);
    movement.Scale(this.transform.forward);
transform.position += movement;
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html